# Text file reading and printing data

Tags: python, beginner, file, python-2.x

**MyText.txt**

```
This is line 1
This is line 2 
Time Taken for writing this#      0 days 0 hrs 1 min 5 sec
Nothing Important
Sample Text
```

**Objective**

To read the text file and find if "Sample Test is present in the file. If present print the time taken to write the file (which is a value already inside the file)"

**My Code**

```
with open('MyText.txt', 'r') as f:
    f.readline()
    for line in f:
        if 'Sample Text' in line:
            print "I have found it"
            f.seek(0)
            f.readline()
            for line in f:
                if 'Time Taken' in line:
                    print line
                    print ' '.join(line.split())
f.close()
```

The code is working fine.  I want to know if this code can be made even better. Considering I am new to Python, I am sure there would be a better way to code this.  Can anyone suggest alternative/faster approaches for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you say, it does look like this code is doing exactly what you want. But it also looks like you are repeating yourself in a couple of places.

If it was me, I would prefer to loop through the file only once and check for both `Sample Text` and `Time Taken` at the same time, and then only print out if the sample text is there:

```
def my_read(my_text):
    time_taken, sample_text = False, False
    with open(my_text) as f:
        for i in f:
            time_taken = ' '.join(i.split()) if 'Time Taken' in i else time_taken
            sample_text = 'I have found it!' if 'Sample Text' in i else sample_text

    # now, if sample text was found, print out
    if sample_text:
        print sample_text
        print time_taken
    return

my_read('MyText.txt')
```

By testing for both, you avoid having to use `f.seek(0)` and start looping through the file again. Of course, this is based on the sample input above - and assumes that there isn't multiple lines with 'Time taken' or 'Sample Text' in them.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
with open('MyText.txt', 'r') as f:
    time = None
    for line in f:
        if 'Time Taken' in line:
            time = line[line.find("#") + 1:].strip()
        if 'Sample Text' in line:
            print "I have found it"
    if time:
        print "Time taken:", time
```

- not sure what that first `f.readline()` was for...
- no need to explicitly invoke `f.close()` when using `with`
- find time taken in the first pass through the file instead of resetting the pointer and seeking again
- you could use `find()` to get the substring after the `#` and `strip()` to get rid of the extra spaces

Comment: Point1 ,Point2 and Point3  are very valid. Thanks for pinting those out.  Point 4:  `print ' '.join(line.split()) print line[line.find("#") + 1:].strip()` give the following output `Time Taken for writing this# 0 days 0 hrs 0 min 14 sec
Time Taken for writing this#     0 days 0 hrs 0 min 14 sec` I prefer first to the second as it looks better formatted.